# Yii, javascript disables a certain field into Undefined Index

Tags: javascript, indexing, yii, undefined

So I was having 2 `dropDownList`s in my _form.php and I have a `radioButtonList` which contains 2 options.

The problem I have is this, when I disable either one, one of the dropdown should be disabled. It did disable, BUT one of them will be turned into Undefined Index, whereas the other one is working fine when disabled.

This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        if(this.value == '0'){
            $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#Booking_service_id").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Booking_service_id").val('0');
        }
        else if(this.value == '1'){             
            $("#Booking_service_id").prop("disabled", false); 
            $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").val('0');
        }
    });
})
```

Okay, so this is what happens. As you can see, IF I were to click on the option '1', the `Booking_clientPackagedService_id` will be disabled and to be submitted. But when I click on the button 'Save' in the form, it says

```
Error 500: Undefined index clientPackagedService_id
```

But If I were to choose on option '0' and submit, everything works just fine. `service_id` isn't giving any problem.

The below is my code to 2 dropDowns:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'clientPackagedService_id'); ?>
    <?php $client = Client::model()->findByPk(1);?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'clientPackagedService_id', CHtml::listData($client->clientPackagedservices(array('condition'=>'client_id='.$client->id.' AND booking_id IS NULL')),'id','packagedServiceInfo')
        ,array(                 
            'disabled'=>'disabled', 
            'prompt'=>'Select Packaged Service....',
            'ajax' => array( 'type'=>'POST', //request type 
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('updateMasseuseAndStationListPSID'), //url to call.
                'data'=>array('clientPackagedService_id'=>'js:this.value', 'dt'=>'js:$("#Booking_date").val()', 'timeStart'=>'js:$("#Booking_timeStart").val()'),
                'dataType'=>'json', 
                'success'=>'js:function(data) {
                    var mass="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'masseuse_id').'"; 
                    $(mass).html(data.masseuse); 
                    $(mass).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                    $(mass+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                    $(mass+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px");

                    var station="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'station_id').'"; 
                    $(station).html(data.station); 
                    $(station).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                    $(station+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                    $(station+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px"); 

                    //alert(data.timeEnd);
                    var timeEnd="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'timeEnd').'";
                    $(timeEnd).val(data.timeEnd);
                }',                         
            ) 
        )
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'clientPackagedService_id'); ?>
    </div><!-- row -->      
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'service_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'service_id',  GxHtml::listDataEx(Service::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)),
        array(              
            //'disabled'=>'disabled', 
            'prompt' => 'Select Service....',
            'ajax' => array( 'type'=>'POST', //request type 
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('updateMasseuseAndStationListSID'), //url to call.
                'data'=>array('service_id'=>'js:this.value', 'dt'=>'js:$("#Booking_date").val()', 'timeStart'=>'js:$("#Booking_timeStart").val()'),
                'dataType'=>'json', 
                'success'=>'js:function(data) {
                    //alert(data.masseuse);
                    var mass="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'masseuse_id').'"; 
                    $(mass).html(data.masseuse); 
                    $(mass).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                    $(mass+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                    $(mass+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px");                              

                    var station="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'station_id').'"; 
                    $(station).html(data.station); 
                    $(station).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                    $(station+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                    $(station+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px"); 

                    //alert(data.timeEnd);
                    var timeEnd="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'timeEnd').'";
                    $(timeEnd).val(data.timeEnd);                       
                }',                         
            ) 
        )); 
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'service_id'); ?>
    </div><!-- row -->
```

**UPDATES After further debugging~**

I found out the reason for it to behave that way.

```
$("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", true);
$("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").val('0');
```

These 2 lines are the reason. Can anyone please advise me? Thanks~

**UPDATES after further further debugging >.<~**

I have a function in actionCreate():

```
$model->bookService($_POST['Booking']['clientPackagedService_id']);
```

basically, when the dropdown is disabled, this method wouldn't go through, thus, throwing an `error 500 clientPackagedService_id Undefined index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in a hidden duplicate field of the dropdownlist, in this case,

`<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'clientPackagedService_id'); ?>`

Because `disabled` dropdownlists won't POST/GET to the PHP server side, therefore, adding in a hidden field will solve the problem